Java JPA find entity with sub array
I will simplify the task a bit, but the problem is the following, I have an Entity that contains id, name and tags.
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @ElementCollection
   private List<String> tags;
}

I need to implement a method in the repository that will search for all Entities that contain in tags the list of tags that are passed to the method, for example there are 3 Entities.
№1 (id=1,name="name1", tags={"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"})
№2 (id=2,name="name2", tags={"tag1" "tag3", "tag4"})
№3 (id=3,name="name3", tags={"tag2", "tag3"})
And the transferred List with tags looks like this {"tag2", "tag3"}. Then this method should return Entity №1 and №3.
I tried to implement repositories in different ways, here are some options.
@Query("SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE :tags MEMBER OF e.tags")
List<Entity> findByTagsContaining(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);

In this case, problems during parsing with query.
Also tried via nativeQuery and @> with PostgreSQL
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_entity_table WHERE tags @> :tags", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findByTagsContaining(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);

Tried using String[] tags, converting to ARRAY like this.
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_entity_table WHERE tags @> ARRAY(:tags)", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> findByTagsContaining(@Param("tags") List<String> tags);

It didn't help.
I know that it is possible to get directly from the Entity using tags.containsAll(tags_list), but it will be slower than through a query.

Yes, Arrays are strange in jdbc, I guess in JPA too. I wouldn't touch it with a ten-foot pole. Read here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html I can suggest to use a native view mapped to an entity.

Ok, I fixed it myself.
Here is the solution.
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE tags @> CAST(ARRAY[:tags] AS TEXT[])", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Sample> findByTags(@Param("tags") String[] tags);

Yes, I know that this is an anti-pattern, because when switching to another database that does not have such an @> operator, this code will not work, that there is no complete protection against SQL injection.
BUT it works and I just wanted to show a simple example solution.
